# Jquery split on row does not work if null

Tags: jquery, html-table

Trying to break a td text on | symbol and display as-

http://jsfiddle.net/XFC5u/102/

```
function addBR($el) {    
$el.html($el.html().split('|').join('<br/>'));
}

addBR($('.myClass'));
```

my issue is when first myClass value is null it shows all following row value null.

like- http://jsfiddle.net/XFC5u/121/

Doing something wrong in looping? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing selector to be this

```
addBR($('.myClass:not(:empty)'));
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. worked but  It shows same TD in all rows of table.looks like only doing first and and displying same in all.here- http://jsfiddle.net/XFC5u/126/